# Android: copy assets on install to sdcard

Tags: java, android, installation, assets

How to copy files from assets to sdcard on install?
Is there any install script option when generating apk?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an async task during your "onCreate" and copy all your files from assets to SDCARD (if available), maybe using a splashscreen if you need the data immediately at start.

There is no way to execute anything after install it's not under application control.
Please also note that SDCARD may not be available if the phone is connected in mass storage mode to a pc.